# Graceful way to kill process

Tags: process, search, kill

After my bash script is done with the selenium server, the script kills it like this:

```
kill `ps -ef | grep selenium | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

While this works and it does kill the selenium script, it also tries to kill the process for `grep selenium` So by the time that process number gets back to the kill command, the process is gone, so it ends up generating an error message. (In other words: it ends up killing two processes, one of them is the real selenium server, the other is a fleeting process that is a side-effect of how I'm doing this command.)

Is there a more graceful way to kill the process, that doesn't have this unintended side-effect?

(FWIW one idea I had: this same script starts up selenium earlier in the script, so maybe if there was a way I could capture the PID when I start up selenium, I could just keep that and kill it directly, instead of grepping for the process ID. The problem is, I don't know how to get that PID, how to use a variable to keep it and how to reference it later in the script. But is that a better way to go about it?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use `pkill selenium` if neither this, nor one of the others work you can keep using your method with another pipe sequence such as

```
kill `ps -ef|grep -i selenium| grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: pkill doesn't work on my server for this, but your improved grep strip helps a lot.

Answer (score 21):

Try the `pgrep` command, which will output the PID of the command you're interested in.

```
pgrep selenium
```

To actually kill the process, use the companion `pkill` command.

```
pkill selenium
```

Comment: I love the elegance of this, but the process looks like this: "root     26401 11997  2 23:20 pts/1    00:00:00 java -jar /home/lm/cron/selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar" so I just changed it to `pgrep java` and it works :-) thanks!

Comment: If you give pgrep the '-f' flag, it will match the pattern against the entire command-line.  So, in this case kill `pgrep -f selenium` should work

Comment: using `pkill` is a lot simpler. `pkill` uses the exact same matching criteria as `pgrep`, so you can do this in 1 command instead of 2 (and having to rely on the output of one).

Answer (score 7):

Try using `grep [s]elenium`.  This will not find the grep process.

Comment: This is a handy trick, indeed. Why does it work?

Comment: @hesse - `grep` uses BREs by default. That is, `[` and `]` show up in `argv` for `grep`, but it doesn't match because `[` and `]` aren't being used literally by `grep`.

Comment: I've often used a `| grep -v grep` component in the pipe. But this is pretty elegant and I like it!

Comment: This is (often) not enough if you have a file in the current working directory with the same name as the process you're grepping for. So, the solution I normally use is: `ps -ef | grep \[s]elenium`. Though I found `lsof` to be a much better alternative to using `ps` and `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

The `killall` command hasn't been mentioned, and I feel it is a useful addition to the repertoire.

```
$ killall selenium
```

You can also use the `-r regex` option to specify a regular expression to match the process name, and even a time value:

```
$ killall -o 5m selenium
```

Kills all selenium processes older than 5 minutes.

Comment: That seems to be unique to non-RHEL/CentOS versions of `killall`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-m 1` switch with the grep command to fetch only the first found process. As long as you sort your processes by PID, ascending, it will work.

Comment: You cannot be sure that the selenium process is using a lower PID.

Comment: FJRA, a process started earlier always gets lower PID. Because the selenium server is started before the 'grep selenium', it will get a lower PID.